# wp.media gallery collection sometimes undefined

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, jquery, media-library

I have a function that includes an external image-source into the media-library (`wp-admin/upload.php`), by making an ajax-call to said image-source, formatting the response appropriately and inserting each image into the library with this function:

```js
wp.media.frame.content.get('gallery').collection.add(formatted);
```

This works really well for me - *most of the time*.
For whatever reason, sometimes i get this exception in the debugger and the images are not added:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add') at addImages

It only happens maybe every 20th-30th reload, and even then it is not consistent. Sometimes the initial load works fine, but on loading more images it does not work, or the other way around.

I tried looking at it in the debugger, and `wp.media.frame.content.get('gallery')` is fine, just `collection` is undefined.

In my PHP, on `wp_enqueue_script` I have `['media', 'media-grid', 'media-editor', 'media-views', 'jquery']` as dependencies, am I maybe missing one here?
But even if - why would it sometimes work on initial load but not on loading more (or vice-versa)?

(Wordpress Version 5.8.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally figured it out, the gallery switches modes sometimes, even without clicking anything (not completely sure what actually happens, I have no idea about Backbone tbh.)

Here is what now works for me:

```js
if(wp.media.frame.content.get('gallery').collection) {
    wp.media.frame.content.get('gallery').collection.add(formatted);
} else {
    wp.media.frame.controller.content.get('gallery').collection.add(formatted);
}
```

The `else`-line won't work when initially loading of media library, so I check before and use the first line if I can. So far it seems to work in all situations (including in media-modal when assigning an image to a custom post-type)